# kerasでのエラー:logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [10,3] and labels shape [30]の解決方法について教えてください！

Tags: python, python3, google-colaboratory, keras

kerasで簡単な分類NNを作ろうとしている初心者です、以下のようなコードを実行したところエラーが発生してしまいました。環境はgoogleColabratoryです。

```
import tensorflow as th
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from google.colab import files
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from keras.utils import to_categorical

uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_csv("wine_class.csv")

target = df["Class"]
data = df.drop("Class", axis=1)
data = data.values
target = target.values
train_data, target_data, train_label, target_label =tts(data, target, train_size=0.7)

train_data = np.array(train_data, np.float32)
target_data = np.array(train_label, np.float32)
train_label = np.array(target_data, np.float32)
target_label = np.array(target_label, np.float32)
train_label = train_label - 1
target_label = target_label - 1
train_label = to_categorical(train_label, num_classes=3)
target_label = to_categorical(target_label, num_classes=3)
Classe = keras.Sequential()
Classe.add(layers.Dense(units=10, activation="relu", input_shape=(124,10)))
Classe.add (layers.Dense(units=3, activation="softmax"))
Classe.compile(optimizer="adam",
           loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
           metrics=["accuracy"])
history = Classe.fit(train_data, train_label,
                 batch_size=10,
                 epochs=10,
                 validation_data=(target_data, target_label))
```

エラー内容

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [10,3] and labels shape [30]
```

code中のwine_class.csvは[ここ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wriphn72GdVHojG3voo2xOVzHByiYIu9/view)からダウウンロードできます。

Comment: 質問のコードを試したところ別のエラー「ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 124, 10), found shape=(None, 10)」で止まりました。エラー内容とコードは合っていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

精度は良くないですが下記で実行できるようになりました。
（手元の環境でval_accuracy: 0.5926）

```
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_csv("wine_class.csv")

target = df["Class"]
data = df.drop("Class", axis=1)
data = data.values
target = target.values
train_data, target_data, train_label, target_label =tts(data, target, train_size=0.7)

train_data = np.array(train_data, np.float32)
target_data = np.array(target_data, np.float32)
train_label = np.array(train_label, np.float32)
target_label = np.array(target_label, np.float32)
train_label = train_label - 1
target_label = target_label - 1
# train_label = to_categorical(train_label, num_classes=3)
# target_label = to_categorical(target_label, num_classes=3)

Classe = keras.Sequential()
Classe.add(layers.Dense(units=10, activation="relu", input_shape=(10,)))
Classe.add (layers.Dense(units=3, activation="softmax"))
Classe.compile(optimizer="adam",
           loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
           metrics=["accuracy"])

history = Classe.fit(train_data, train_label,
                 batch_size=10,
                 epochs=10,
                 validation_data=(target_data, target_label))
```

元のコードの下記部分は記入ミスだと思うので見直してください。

> target_data = np.array(train_label, np.float32)
> train_label = np.array(target_data, np.float32)

他の変更点は、目的変数のカテゴリ化を止めたこととレイヤーの入力形状を修正しました。元のコードと見比べてください。

説明変数を標準化することで精度を良くできますのでトライしてみてください。
手元の環境ではval_accuracy: 0.9815となりました。

Comment: ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 124
  y sizes: 54
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.というエラーが出ました